# Имя Святополк

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Что означает славянское имя Святополк? Корень "свят" - это понятно, а "полк"? Не о войсковой же единице речь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да в общем-то и о единице тоже. 
Только "полк" здесь в древнерусском (вернее - общеславянском) понимании - войско вообще.
Святополк - [имеющий] святое войско.